# Will 40km E-Bike trip in Texel Island(Holland) be hard for untrained people?

Tags: electric-bike

I'm planning to have a trip in Texel island(North-Holland) in April,

We are a group of 5 people, 22 years old, who know how to ride a bike

But we do not train on cycling.

Will a trip of 40km, in 8 hours+-, with an E-Bike be very hard for us?

Thank you very much.

Comment: As long as the E-bikes have a range of 40 km on the terrain you are traveling (range will vary depending on hills), you should be fine. 40 km would be quite a short ride, and even at a moderate pace of 20km/h (most e-bikes max out around 28 km/h depending on jurisdiction) it would only be 2 hours of actual cycling.  As long as your group is in moderately good physical condition, it should not be hard.

Comment: Yeah, but notice that all of us are not in fit(don't cycle, run, go to gym, etc...). Just normal people with jobs.

Comment: I meant moderately fit as in not majorly overweight or other physical conditions that would lead to problems of increased activity.  I recommend that you see if you can rent some e-bikes at home (or just a single one to share for the day) to get a feel of what it's like if you are unsure.

Comment: I am offended that you imply normal people with jobs are not fit.

Comment: @Blam Oh, I wouldn't be. My job interferes with my fitness all the time because my boss has this silly idea I should be sitting at a desk all day instead of riding my bike.

Comment: @Blam Lol, I didn't mean that people with jobs aren't in fit ^^, the opposite is correct!

Comment: 40 km is about 25 miles. Most people of average (and below average) fitness can easily complete that in well under 8 hours on flat land on a regular bicycle.

Comment: My only real concern would be how well they knew how to ride a bike.  Sure, quite a few people learn how to ride bikes as kids, but many of them stop before they've even had a chance to ride with gears.  If they haven't biked in a long time, then riding an e-bike might actually be more difficult than riding a plain old pedal bike. Depending on traffic, road condition, and other factors, some people might actually have trouble handling the bike itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

40km over 8 hours is just 5km/h

Looking back to when I first started cycling (and was unfit), even then I would average something between 15-20km/h. On that basis alone you should have ample time to complete your ride.

Texel is a beautiful place, there is little traffic (plus you will have many traffic-free, tarmac cycle routes) and it is perfectly flat. The only foreseeable problem will be the wind, so make sure you dress accordingly. To give an idea, I was staying once near Alkmaar, and rode up to Den Helder at around 40km/h. The return journey, however, was 20km/h - that is the difference the wind makes over there, and there really is no escape.

But having said all that, that sounds exactly like when an eBike would be useful.

Remember to carry some windproof gear.

Comment: If you have not been there, and you have good weather, then I would definitely recommend a visit to Vuurtoren lighthouse. Unfortunately it is right at the other end of the island from the ferry!

Comment: So ... walking will do just fine as well :D (5km/h)

Comment: 5km/h is a typical walking speed, but I think walking that distance would be quite tiring, especially for someone not used to long walks. Cycling would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No you'll be fine and (if the weather allows) you'll have a wonderful day.

Longer answer: You are on an e-bike, 40km is about two hours of riding on an e-bike. This is independent of fitness, because you are on an e-bike. Saddlesoreness (is that a word?) might be an issue, but given that you have 8 hours total you can bike short bits with long breaks in between to rest your tender bits. If it turns out range is an issue you'll come across dozens of places where you can use those same six hours you have left to charge your batteries. Texel isn't crowded by dutch standards but it is by no means empty.

The highest point of Texel is 15.3m above sea level, the lowest point about 1m below, so hills are not an issue either.

More than your fitness level I expect the weather (rain and/or wind) might be an issue.